# Accessing "Options" via JS API [Paw App]

Tags: paw-app

I wrote a Code Generator and would like to access the request options (e.g. "Timeout", "Follow Redirects"). Is it possible to retrieve those values? I searched the [Extensions Reference](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Reference) but couldn't find any reference to them.

Comment: Thanks for asking, Matthew. Unfortunately, not yet. It's something small and would be nice to have though. Will add that on our todo list.